# startWith() that returns Subject

Tags: rxjs, observable

I want to emit values using Subject with default value.

`startWith("def")` is the method for this.

```
subject = new Rx.Subject().startWith("def value");
```

unfortunately `startWIth` returns `Observable` and therefore I cannot use `onNext()`, which is the sole reason I am using Subject in the first place. What is the workaround for this problem?

```
subject.onNext("next val"); //cannot call onNext, it is not a function of Observable
```

Answer (score 5):

Just keep track of both the observable and the subject.  I usually do something like...

```
export class FooService {

  private _foos: Subject<Foo> = new subject<Foo>();

  public get foos: Observable<Foo> {
    return this._foos.startsWith(...);
  }

  public emitFoo(foo: Foo) {
    this._foos.next(foo);
  }

}
```

Comment: can u provide any example

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't entirely clear.  If you want all observers to see "def value" before anything else, then use @Pace's answer.

But if you want all observers to start with "the most recently emitted value", and use "def value" if they subscribe before you emit the first value, then use a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject("default val");
subject.subscribe(...); // sees "default val", then anything you emit.

subject.next("foo");
subject.subscribe(...); // sees "foo", then anything else you emit (does not see "default val")
```